# Implicit data type conversion in C

Tags: c, type-conversion, operator-precedence

```
int a=98, b=10;
float c;
c=a/b;
```

Output: c=9

I know because of implicit type conversion, `c` value is 9 not 9.8 but then I encountered this question:

```
int a,b,c,d;
a=40;
b=35;
c=20;
d=10;
printf("%d",a*b/c-d);
```

output: 60

Now if we see the precedence for equation is right to left and according to BODMAS rule b/c(35/20) will be performed first so 35/20 = 1.75 and then implicit conversion to integer make it to 1 and then rest will follow up the answer must be 30 but the output is 60 which is correct answer. Can you explain me why?

Comment: what is bodmas rule? a*b will be executed first

Comment: Operator precedence for * and / in C is left-to-right: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence So `a*b` will be done first. It,s equivalent to writing `((a*b)/c)-d`. (wrote as answer)

Comment: yeah true because it is a float

Comment: Ref [BODMAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Mnemonics)

Comment: `35/20 = 1.75` is not so here as it is `int` math.  `35/20` --> 1.  IAC, the `40*35` happens first like  `((a*b)/c)-d` using only `int` math and no type conversions.

Comment: @AntonH yeah operator precedence is left to right thanks

Comment: Ah... another victim of this stupid abbreviation, seeing  `D` comes before `M`...

Comment: Should have used PEMDAS instead ...

Comment: @AntonH Any of these are harmful. Just take a look at all of these "holy" wars on the social media because of not understanding this stuff. It's really not that hard to memorize the rules without using these acronyms.

Comment: The first part of the question is unrelated to the second part — and you don't even ask a question about the `c = a / b;` expression.  It should really be removed from the question.

Answer (score 1):

Operator precedence in C for `*` and `/` in C is left-to-right: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

So `a*b` will be done first. It's equivalent to writing `((a*b)/c)-d`.

Answer (score 0):

So your execution will follow *left to right* execution for `/` and `*`:

```
((40 * 35) / 20) - 10 = ((1400) / 20) - 10 = (70) - 10 = 60
```